# How to control Google Home Accessories From Different Android App

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-smart-home

Fetch and control Home app accessories from Different Android App

Scenario -

1. Create TestApp
2. Fetch Google Home Accessories(Devices)
3. Control(On/Off a bulb) from TestApp

Can we achieve this scenario with or without cloud support?

Answer (score 2):

We have an upcoming Android API to control smart home devices called Google Home APIs, that we [announced at Google IO](https://developers.home.google.com/io) earlier this month. You can [sign up](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeWeft-jJ8qgwDyDpKE6bwjUmX_0576NqQap_Qb70uvNjcssQ/viewform) for the developer preview, which we will start to include developers in the upcoming months.

Hope it helps,